# How to add css class in li at multipe breadcrubms in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to add **css class** in BreadCrubms. I am able to do it using template, 
Example

```
 $this->Breadcrumbs->setTemplates([
    'item' => '<li class ="breadcrumb-item" {{attrs}}><a href="{{url}}"{{innerAttrs}}>{{title}}</a></li>{{separator}}',
  ]);
```

But problem is when I am trying to add **css active class** in list.

I have tried below code in crumbs, but it's not working

```
$this->Breadcrumbs->add([
        [
            'title' => 'Home', 
            'url' => ['controller' => 'Blogs', 'action' => 'home'],
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'View-'.$article->title, 
            'url' => ['controller' => 'Blogs', 'action' => 'view', $article->id],
            ['class' => 'active']
        ]
    ]);
```

Here active class not appearing in inspector. How can I add this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the docs don't show that type of usage. If you add (multiple) crumbs as arrays, then all values need to use string indices, ie the options need to be passed using the `options` key:

```
[
    'title' => 'View-'.$article->title, 
    'url' => ['controller' => 'Blogs', 'action' => 'view', $article->id],
    'options' => ['class' => 'active'],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution: Works for CakePhp 4.xxx

```
$this->Breadcrumbs->add([
    [
        'title' => 'Home', 
        'url' => ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index'],
        'options' => ['class' => 'breadcrumb-item'],
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'xyz', 
        'url' => ['controller' => 'xxx', 'action' => 'yyy'],
        'options' => ['class' => 'breadcrumb-item-active'],
    ]
]);
```

?>